# I want to give radius to shadow shown inside a layout in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to give shadow inside a cardview and got solution like shown below :

[image]

but I also want to give radius to shadow as well which I'm not able to do,

Here's my code for the same :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_20sdp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
                android:centerX="0.97"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#5C000000"
                android:startColor="#00FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
                android:centerY="0.1"
                android:endColor="#00FF0000"
                android:startColor="#6B000000" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_20sdp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take transfers image like a shadow you want the top layout.
or
create gradient drawable.
Try something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#555994"
        android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners 
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```